# Yeoman copy directory without templating

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am using yeoman for creating a scaffold for my app.

I want to copy all the directory recursively thats why I am using `this.directory` method

```
this.directory('views/static/views', '.views/static/views');
```

Now whenever I am running it shows an error showing `<%= title %> in file index.html during copying is not defined.`

This `<%= title %>` is not the part of Templating but I am using this for my other purpose.

**I want to disable the templating while copying using `this.directory` method.?**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I figure it out.
using `this.fs.copy` copies recursively without templating.

```
writing: function () {
    this.fs.copy(
      this.templatePath('views/static/views'),
      this.destinationPath('.views/static/views')
    );
  }
```

Now when templating the correct syntax should be

```
writing: function () {
    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath('index.html'),
      this.destinationPath('public/index.html'),
      { title: 'Templating with Yeoman' }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Awesome! I needed a combination of both, thanks for the info.